# Escape all backslashes from a Read-Host input string

Tags: powershell, path, read-host

I'm building a simple tool to compile C++ and C# code faster, and with compiling, you generally paste in the path of your file/folder when you `cd` into the directory. The problem with this is that the path that is pasted in usually includes backslashes. These are in turn read as escape characters to the terminal, and produces multiple errors going on about unknown escape sequences. So what I need to know is, is there some way of escaping the backslashes found in the path, or in other terms, "safely" read the string?

I've tried a few different things, and none of them work. Like in other languages, find and replace does nothing, it just causes more errors.

Comment: If you are just getting a path you could do something as simple as `$Path = (Read-Host "Enter Path") -replace '\\','\\'` which will double each backslash. If the path is part of a larger string that could contain other valid escape characters you'll need something more complicated to locate the path substring and perform the replace.

Comment: Wow, that's easier than I thought it would be. I kind of forgot about the `-replace` as I don't use it as much as others, like `-match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[regex]` class has an `Escape` method:

```
PS > $path = Read-Host "Path"
Path: C:\My Folder\subfolder\file.txt
PS > [regex]::Escape($path)
C:\\My\ Folder\\subfolder\\file\.txt
```

Comment: Maybe `[regex]::Escape($path)`? `$input` is an automatic variable (Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that's passed to a function.)

Comment: oops, you're right. That was a typo

Comment: Note that this will also escape other valid path characters that also happen to be regex characters, not just backslashes - e.g. ```[regex]::escape("c:\my [file].txt")``` -> ```c:\\my\ \[file]\.txt``` - the ```[``` and ```.``` in the path are escaped as well. Maybe that's what you want, maybe it's not, but it's worth being aware of...

Comment: Yeah it's not a perfect solution but escaping innocuous characters usually shouldn't cause any issues imo. But it's possible.